# "Content Not Supposed to Be Outside 'Script' or 'asp:Content' Regions"

Tags: asp.net, .net

I'm starting to learn ASP.NET and it's the little things that are really annoying with Visual Studio Web Dev Express. I keep getting the error "Content Not Supposed To Be Outside 'Script' or 'asp:Content' Regions" - so I put content inside an `asp:content` container and it doesn't disappear. I also get the same sort of error with declaring the DocType. Any suggestions to fix this. Also on an off-note: is there any better IDE's to code ASP.NET?

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Hello VS2010</title>
</head>
<body>
    <asp:content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
                <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server">
                    Hello World
                </asp:Literal>
            </div>
        </form>
    </asp:content>
</body>
</html>
```

**Master Page**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Site.master.cs" Inherits="SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
    <div class="page">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="title">
                <h1>
                    My ASP.NET Application
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="loginDisplay">
                <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                    <AnonymousTemplate>
                        [ <a href="~/Account/Login.aspx" ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a> ]
                    </AnonymousTemplate>
                    <LoggedInTemplate>
                        Welcome <span class="bold"><asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" /></span>!
                        [ <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="~/"/> ]
                    </LoggedInTemplate>
                </asp:LoginView>
            </div>
            <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
                <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About"/>
                    </Items>
                </asp:Menu>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have a MasterPAge containing already Doc type and <head> ?

Comment: IDK this tutorial hasn't gotten to master pages yet - it just expects me to work in Default and change things to show output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Master pages are a kind of template applied to all of your pages. Here it seems you use one without knowing it

```
MasterPageFile="~/Site.master"
```

In the masterPage you have all the content you want to be common to all your pages and a asp:content region where you can add content for each page.

So here you can try to remove the masterPage reference or just Adding and removing things in the asp:content region.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)'s the msdn link about MasterPages. I think it really necessary to understand masterPages to learn asp.net.

Comment: In the end I just deleted everything and added a new Web Form. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**New Reply:**

Well, okay.

So first things first only one form tag per page, that includes pages within master pages.

You don't need the form tag or the html, body or head tag on your Web form, only your master page.

So Page.aspx code should be like: http://codepaste.net/87n474

Note you need to include all content areas in your aspx page that are available in your master page.

**Original Reply:**

Couple of things.

- Check your masterpage layout and see if there is any content misplace in that. (paste it here as well)
- Also related to your masterpage, I don't see much point in having a masterpage if you're putting **all** your HTML markup inside the asp.aspx page.

Your doctype should be:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Note the small differences in capitalisation.

Finally, the only IDE any better than web dev express is the full version of Visual Studio, there isn't any better version for creating and debugging asp.net sites than the latest version of visual studio.

Comment: That's to bad :/

I updated my main question with my master.aspx - though I haven't edited it so I mean i'm unsure why there would be a problem with it by default.